# Filter using select input in React and RxJS

Tags: reactjs, rxjs

I want to pre-populate some inputs based on a select input in React. At the moment I am using a behaviour subject to update a state value which works, however the code is quite verbose

```
type User = {
  name: string
}

const hello$ = new BehaviorSubject<User | null>(null)

const UserDetails = (props: {id: string, users: User[]}) => {
  const [user, setUser] = React.useState<User| null>(null)
  
  useObservable(hello$, setUser)

  return (
    <form>
      <NativeSelect 
        value={sl?.name}
        onChange={(event) => { 
hello$.next(props.users.find(({name}) => name === event.target.value) || null)
        }}
        name="user" 
        label="User Name" 
        data={props.users?.map(({name}) => name )}
      >
        <option value={undefined}>Select User</option>
        {props.users?.map(({name}) => <option value={name}> {name} </option> )}
      </NativeSelect>
      <Text>{user?.name}</Text>
    </form>
  )
}
```

In this example I am filtering in the onChange handler on the Select. I do not like this, I would prefer if I pass the value to the behaviour subject, which then pipes it to another observable that filters it and then emits an event to update state.
How do I achieve this?